# Why my javamail program not running through jdeveloper?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, jdeveloper, hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-maf

I am working on Oracle MAF app and using Java mail API for sending outlook meeting requests. I can successfully send mail from java command-line, but when trying same using Mobile app, the code doesn't go after where creating "MimeMessage" class object.

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
```

printStackTrace() shows this exception:

> 06-09 10:54:43.146: D/JVM(16075): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework -
>   Utility - invoke] InvocationTargetException Error: ERROR
>   [oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfException] - Error invoking
>   method 'sendMail' in 'class beans.UtilBean'
>
> 06-09 12:14:07.466: I/System.out(3760): [SEVERE -
>   oracle.adfmf.framework - adf.mf.internal - logError] Request:
>   {"classname":"oracle.adfmf.framework.api.Model","method":"processBatchRequests","params":[false,[{"classname":"oracle.adfmf.framework.api.Model","method":"evaluateMethodExpression","params":["#{UtilBean.sendMail}",[{".type":"oracle.adfmf.amx.event.ActionEvent"}],"void",["oracle.adfmf.amx.event.ActionEvent"]]}]]}
>   exception: {"message":"Error invoking method 'sendMail' in 'class
>   beans.UtilBean'",".exception":true,"severity":"ERROR",".type":"oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfException"}

```
Full source code of my class is here:

package beans;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import oracle.adfmf.amx.event.ActionEvent;

public class Email {

    private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "mail_host_name";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "smtp_user_id";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "smtp_auth_pass";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PORT = "smtp_port";
    private static final String MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS = "from_addr";
    private static final String RECEIPENT_1 = "receipent_1_addr";
    private static final String RECEIPENT_2 = "receipent_2_addr";

    public void sendEmail(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_AUTH_PORT);

        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();

        //Get the session object
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

        //compose message
        try {
            System.out.print("CALLED0"); //I can see this in Logcat Logs
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession); // Program stuck here
            System.out.print("CALLED1");//I can not see this in Logcat Logs
            message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
            message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
            message.addHeaderLine("component=vevent");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(RECEIPENT_1));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(RECEIPENT_2));
            message.setSubject("Outlook Meeting Request Using JavaMail");

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer buffer =
                sb.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" + "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n" +
                          "VERSION:2.0\n" + "METHOD:REQUEST\n" + "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
                          "ATTENDEE;CN=\"Attendee1\";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;MAILTO:attendee1@addendant.com\n" +
                          "ATTENDEE;CN=\"Attendee2\";ROLE=OPT-PARTICIPANT;MAILTO:attendee2@addendant.com\n" +
                          "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:org@org.com\n" + "DTSTART:20050406T073000Z\n" +
                          "DTEND:20050406T080000Z\n" + "LOCATION:conf\n" + "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" + "SEQUENCE:0\n" +
                          "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000A0A742E5073AC5010000000000000000100\n" +
                          " 0000029606C073D82204AB6C77ACE6BC2FBE2\n" + "DTSTAMP:20050405T122004Z\n" +
                          "CATEGORIES:Meeting\n" + "DESCRIPTION:What are you doing?\n\n" + "SUMMARY:How are you?\n" +
                          "PRIORITY:5\n" + "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" + "BEGIN:VALARM\n" + "TRIGGER:PT1440M\n" +
                          "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" + "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" + "END:VALARM\n" + "END:VEVENT\n" +
                          "END:VCALENDAR\n");
            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
            messageBodyPart.setContent(buffer.toString(), "text/calendar");
            // Create a Multipart
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            // Add part one
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(multipart);

            //send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("message sent successfully");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
            String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

In Email class I added print statement before and after where creating "MimeMessage" class object, I am able to see first print in logcat but not second.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Updated. Please check. printStackTrace() displays only these exceptions.

Comment: Try cleaning up these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and see if that helps.  If not, add try/catch around the call and print out the exception and stack trace; it looks like ADF is hiding the important part of the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying java project on Web logic server as a web service (as a .war package) worked for me.